# Why can't I ask questions?

Tags: discussion, support, asking-questions, banning

I have been banned from asking questions? Can one bad question equal a question ban?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Out of ten questions you've asked, seven of them are deleted and all of them had negative scores except one. Stack Exchange's algorithm for deciding to question-ban someone includes those deleted questions. Not even the mods have any control over question and answer bans so we can't do anything about that.

Tl;dr: you didn't only have one bad question; you had seven with negative score.

Please [read this post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/86997/256282) to see how the ban might be able to be lifted.

Comment: Can I have them undeleted so I can improve them?

Comment: @Muze No. You can either wait out the timer before you get more chances or earn some reputation by providing some quality answers. Do some research, answer something well, and that will help the system decide to let you ask more questions. Next time pay attention to the warnings (which you were shown BEFORE asking that many questions) rather than plowing ahead ignoring them until you get blacklisted. This goes for any site in the SE network (and is a good life rule of thumb).